# Limit of binomial random variables

Tags: probability

Let $X_n $ be binomial $B(p_n,n) $ and $\lambda = n p_n $ constant. Suppose $A_n = \{ X_n \geq 1 \} $ and suppose $Y$ is poisson ( $\lambda) $. I want to show that

$$ \lim_{ n\to \infty} P( X_n = j | A_n) = P(Y = j | Y \geq 1 ) $$

I am sort of confused since we know that

$$ P( X_n = j | A_n) = \frac{ P ( \{ X_n = j \} \cap A_n ) }{P(A_n) } $$

Isnt the fraction above just $1$ since $P ( \{ X_n = j \} \cap A_n ) = P( X_n \geq 1 ) = P(A_n) $ ??

Comment: $j$ doesn't have to be 1. To get 1 you have to sum over all $j$ greater than or equal to one.

Answer (score 0):

The set inclusion $\{X_n=j\}\cap A_n\subset A_n$ is valid. But the reverse inclusion is false: If $X_n\ge1$ it doesn't follow that $X_n=j$ and $X_n\ge1$. So the fraction above is not $1$.

To calculate $P(X_n=j|A_n)$ consider two cases: (1) $j=0$ and (2) $j\ge1$. In the first case the answer is zero because you can't have $X_n=0$ and $X_n\ge1$. In the second case the numerator $P(X_n=j,X_n\ge1)$ simplifies to $P(X_n=j)$, because when $j\ge1$ the event $\{X_n=j,X_n\ge1\}$ is the same as the event $\{X_n=j\}$.